# Jtable click to display information not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

I have created a Jtabel `tab_an`and I've populated it from my data base with this code:

```
 private void miseajour_congan(){
    try{


String sql1 ="select c.matricule,c.nom,e.prénom,c.cong_ID,c.nature,c.statut_dem,c.date_d,c.date_f,c.solde_an,c.report_an,c.durée from congé c  where c.nature = 'annuel'";


   ps1=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
   rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
   tab_an.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));

      }catch(Exception st){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, st);
       }
    }
```

I've also created a Jpanel with some of swing components (checkbox,combobox,textfield,Jdatechooser,Jspinner) and I've added the Jtable to the Jpanel. The problem is that when I click on a row on the Jtable I want all the information contained in the table to be displayed. To do this, I'm using this code but when I click nothing happens and nothing is displayed:

```
 private void tab_anMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
   try {
    int ligne =tab_an.getSelectedRow();
    String Tab_clic=(tab_an.getModel().getValueAt(ligne,0).toString());
 String sql = "SELECT c.matricule,c.nom,c.prénom,c.cong_ID,c.nature,c.statut_dem,c.date_d,c.date_f,c.solde_an,c.report_an,c.durée "
         + "from congé c where  c.cong_ID='"+Tab_clic+"'  ";

   rs=ps.executeQuery(sql);
   while(rs.next())
   { 
    String n = rs.getString("nom");
    String p = rs.getString("prénom");
    StringBuilder  st = new StringBuilder();
    st.append(n).append("  ").append(p);
    String l = st.toString();
    empcombo.setSelectedItem(l);

   IDtxt1.setText(rs.getString("cong_ID"));

    matric_txt.setText(rs.getString("matricule"));

   ((JTextField)datede_chooz.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(rs.getString("date_d"));
  ((JTextField)datefinann_chooz.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(rs.getString("date_f"));  
  soldan_spin.setValue(rs.getInt("solde_an"));
  reportan_spin.setValue(rs.getInt("report_an"));

  String r =rs.getString("durée");
  String [] t = r.split(" ");
  int num = 0;
  if (t.length>=2)
  {num = Integer.parseInt(t[0]);
  duran_spin.setValue(num);
  joursemaine_combo.setSelectedItem(t[1]);}
  String x = rs.getString("statut_dem");
  if ( x.equals("approuvé"))
  {
      approve_check.setSelected(true);
  }

  else  if (x.equals("rejeté"))  
  {
       reject_check.setSelected(true);
  }
    else  if (x.equals("en attente") )

    {
        attente_check.setSelected(true);
    }

   }}catch(Exception ej)
   {  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ej);
           ej.printStackTrace();}
}
```

This is The DESC of the table *congé*

```
nom varchar(255) YES NULL
prénom varchar(255) YES NULL
statut_dem varchar(100) YES NULL
cong_ID int(11) NO PRI NULL auto_increment
matricule int(11) NO MUL NULL
nature enum('annuel','compensateur','maladie','exceptionel') YES NULL
solde_an float YES NULL
report_an float YES NULL 
solde_comp float YES NULL
report_comp float YES NULL
solde_mal int(11) YES NULL
solde_excep int(11) YES NULL
cause_excep enum('mariage','décés') YES NULL
date_d varchar(100) YES NULL
date_f varchar(100) YES NULL
durée varchar(50) YES NULL
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SelectionListiner not a MouseListiner.